# Java code to pull data from a cloud api

Tags: java, cloud

How can I get a Java code that pulls data from a given cloud api?
Eg: I want to extract my fitbit data(steps walked) from Fitbit cloud and give it as a result in Java program. Is there any Java code to do so?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get data from api you have to make request to it. Here is example how to make HTTP get or post request. [EXAMPLE](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/)